# How do you get the values greater than a number from a list in scheme?

Tags: list, function, scheme, conditional-statements

How do you extract and return as a list all the numbers greater than a number that are found in a given list?
I know how to return the max but this is different.
An example is `(gfifty ‘(a b (c d) 1 56 67 g))` to `(56 67)`
In the example above, it returns a list containing values greater than 50.
Teach me master. :)

Comment: What result do you expect for an input of `'(a b (100 d) 1 56 67)`?

Answer (score 4):

The idiomatic solution would be to use [`filter`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29):

```
(filter (lambda (x) (and (number? x) (> x 50)))
        '(a b (c d) 1 56 67 g))
=> '(56 67)
```

To see how to write an implementation from scratch, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18028825/201359) answer. But if the search is recursive (if we must also search inside sublists), then study [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18038636/201359) other answer.

Comment: thanks for the shortcut. the link to the implementation really helped me to understand how it works.